# chrome's alternative for firebug's evaluation console?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

I'm using chrome for a new website, and I'm doing some javascript debugging.
One of my favorite techniques to debug nested expressions is to put a breakpoint, enter an expression in firebug's input panel in the console tab and press run. 
But I don't see this feature in chrome. I'm probably overlooking something. Is it there? And where can I find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it right from this page: Hit **CTRL+SHIFT+J**, click the **Sources tab**, choose **chromes-alternative-for-firebug-evaluation-console** from the file drop down on the left, click on line 41 to create a break point. Now refresh the page and your breakpoint will stop the debugger.

[image: Chrome Debugger]

Comment: Is there a way to get user input from the console (like what Java's scanner class does?)

Comment: @AndersonGreen Please do not hijack questions, you should ask a new question so that others can search for it and benefit from the answer

Comment: Here's the relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299356/how-to-get-input-from-chromes-javascript-console

Answer (score 4):

**Ctrl + Shift + I** will open Chrome's Developer's Tools. Or (Chrome v9): Options -> Tools -> Developer Tools. **Ctrl + Shift + J** is a keyboard shortcut for the Javascript console.

Under the **Scripts** tab, you can click on the line number to set a breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try right clicking on the page and choosing "Inspect Element" which should open the developer tools for you. Then you can click the **Scripts** tab like Harmen said.

Comment: I said it out the top of my head, but it _is_ Ctrl+Shift+I ;)