# Javascript: How do you take user input and store into a variable without any HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-input, console.log

I want to ask the user through the console to enter a number. I then want to store it into a variable to have it used for a function etc. Here is an example of what I have done. When i do this it says ReferenceError: readline is not defined

```
console.log("Enter your guess and press <Enter>: /t" );
var userNumber = readline();
```

I am just trying to create an interactive js console app for now.

Edit:
Here is my source code http://repl.it/NeI/4

Comment: `var answer = prompt("Enter a number");`

Comment: Of course readline is not defined. You can't make stuff up :|

Comment: "console" as in browser's console (does not provide any "read" capabilities) or regular OS console (like CMD in Windows with running script via CScript)?

Comment: The console is already interactive.

Comment: For some reason, i thought readline() was a built in function.

Comment: Do you mean a terminal console? If so - then you need to be running this with node.js.

Comment: Also the reason why your code isn't working [here](http://repl.it/NeI/4) is the unresolved while loop...

Comment: i know there is some logical error in the while loop but i cant figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
var guess = window.prompt("Enter your guess", "Number from 1 to 9");
console.log(guess);
```

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure about that either

Comment: Well it's mostly fine, +20-2 is still +18.

Answer (score 3):

The console does not do what you are hoping it will in this situation.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console) is the API documentation from Mozilla, and [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api) are the Chrome docs.

The console intent is to display information from your application for debugging purposes, with some minor helper functions.

Answer (score 0):

Developer tools or Firebug console can't receive user data this way, there's no `read` or `readline` methods. You have to use a window method called `"prompt"` .

```
var data = prompt("Type something to me baby!");
console.log(data);
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299356/how-to-get-input-from-chromes-javascript-console) another question addressing this same doubt.